# Given a start and end date, create an array of the dates between the two

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now, I have this on my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var days = [
            { Date: new Date($('#hfEventStartDate').val()) },
            { Date: new Date($('#hfEventEndDate').val()) }
        ];
    });
</script>

<asp:HiddenField ID="hfEventStartDate" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfEventEndDate" runat="server" />
```

I'm setting hfEventStartDate and hfEventEndDate when the page loads. With my code right now, it creates an array with two values: the start date and the end date. But I'd like to also have the array contain all the dates in between. How can I do that?

Comment: Please try something yourself before posting a question; most people here will frown on requests for code like this one.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could make use of `setDate(getDate() + 1)` to 'iterate' over all days: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/4GeFD/1/.

```
$("#hfEventStartDate").val(new Date - 24 * 3600 * 1000 * 7 - 1);
$("#hfEventEndDate").val(new Date - 0);

function getAllDays() {
    var s = new Date($('#hfEventStartDate').val() - 0);
    var e = new Date($('#hfEventEndDate').val() - 0);
    var a = [];

    while(s < e) {
        a.push(s);
        s = new Date(s.setDate(
            s.getDate() + 1
        ))
    }

    return a;
};

alert(getAllDays().join("\n"));
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's a go: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dbKCB/)

```
var date1 = new Date();
var date2 = new Date(2010, 0, 1);
var day;
var between = [date1];

while(date2 <= date1) {
    day = date1.getDate()
    date1 = new Date(date1.setDate(--day));  
    between.push(date1);
}

console.log(between);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
        start = new Date("August 13,2011");
        future = new Date("October 13, 2011");
        range = []
        mil = 86400000 //24h
        for (var i=start.getTime(); i<future.getTime();i=i+mil) {

          range.push(new Date(i))

       //or for timestamp
       //range.push(i)
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

try [momment.js](http://momentjs.com) and [twix](http://icambron.github.io/twix.js)

```
var itr = moment.twix(new Date('2012-01-15'),new Date('2012-01-20')).iterate("days");
var range=[];
while(itr.hasNext()){
    range.push(itr.next().toDate())
}
console.log(range);
```

live:http://jsfiddle.net/aswani/GNPQc/

Answer (score 2):

I have read the given answer and this is what I came out with. 
Note that I started from the answer of @pimvdb

```
// return an array composed of a list of the days' number 
// from 1 month ago until today, not included
function getAllDays() {
 var e = moment();
 var s = moment().subtract('months', 1);
 var a = []
  // While the updated start date is older, perform the loop.
  while(s.isBefore(e)) {
   // Update the format according to moment js documentations format().
   a.push(s.format("MMM - DD"));
   s = s.add('days', 1);
  }
 return a;
}
```

Simply call the function anywhere in your code:

```
getAllDays();
```

see also: [MomentJs library](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me too:

```
$("#hfEventStartDate").val(new Date - 24 * 3600 * 1000 * 7 - 1);
$("#hfEventEndDate").val(new Date - 0);

function getAllDays() {
    var s = new Date($('#hfEventStartDate').val() - 0);
    var e = new Date($('#hfEventEndDate').val() - 0);
    var a = [];
    while(s <= e) {
        a.push(new Date(s));
        s.setDate(s.getDate() + 1);
    }

    return a;
};

alert(getAllDays().join("\n"));
```

Is the same code that pimvdb published with some minor changes, but it gives a different result. It took me 4 hours trying to understand why, and this is what i think happens with pimvdb code:

```
1 loop
a[0] = S1 = $("#hfEventStartDate").val(new Date - 24 * 3600 * 1000 * 7 - 1);
//2013-09-01

2 loop
a[0] = s1.setDate(s1.getDate() + 1); // 2013-09-02
a[1] = s2 = new Date(s1.setDate(s1.getDate() + 1)) // 2013-09-02

3 loop
a[0] = s1; // 2013-09-02
a[1] = s2.setDate(s2.getDate() + 1); // 2013-09-03
a[2] = s3 = new Date(s2.setDate(s2.getDate() + 1)) // 2013-09-03

and so on...
```

I'm not sure if this was deliberately intended by pimvdb but his code lefts out the starting day, which in my example would be 2013-09-01. But even if it was intended, why not leaving out the last day as well? at least that's what while(s < e) seemed intended for, but the last day is included in the final array.

I'm sorry I may be wrong, I have never worked with object orientated programing, but trying to understand why a[0] was getting changed on the second loop after already been assigned on the fist one made me absolutely insane. Hope I'm not so wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an interval to do what you want.

```
var tstamp = 0;


function timer() {

    console.log(tstamp);
    tstamp = new Date().getTime()
}

var i = setInterval(timer, 1000);

//when no more needed
clearInterval(i)
```